# Making zooms shortcuts in SciChart WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, scichart

1) I want to create zoom shortcuts- 5 minutes before.
10 minutes
hour and 24 hours from the lasttick.

I made this code and it doesnt work right.

what should i fix?

```
    ZoomOptions = new List<ZoomOption>
    {
        new ZoomOption("5M", TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)),
        new ZoomOption("30M", TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30)),
        new ZoomOption("1H", TimeSpan.FromHours(1)),
        new ZoomOption("1D", TimeSpan.FromHours(24)),
    };

    SelectedZoomOption = ZoomOptions.Last();

private void UpdateZoom()
{
    if (_viewModel == null ||
        _viewModel.SelectedZoomOption == null ||
        _viewModel.LastTick == null) return;

    var timeSpan = _viewModel.SelectedZoomOption.Time;
    var latestXValue = _viewModel.LastTick.Time;
    var startDate = latestXValue - timeSpan;

    var axis = (CategoryDateTimeAxis)Chart.XAxis;
    if (axis == null || axis.VisibleRange == null) return;
    var calc = (ICategoryCoordinateCalculator)axis.GetCurrentCoordinateCalculator();
    if (calc == null) return;
    var startIndex = calc.TransformDataToIndex(startDate);

    var max = ((IndexRange)axis.VisibleRange).Max;
    var desiredMax = calc.TransformDataToIndex(latestXValue) + 5;
    if (timeSpan < TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10))
    {
        max = desiredMax;
    }
    else if (max == desiredMax)
    {
        max += 100;
    }
    axis.VisibleRange = new IndexRange(startIndex, max);
}
```

2) why when i dont have graph history but only new ticks i cant see the graph from beginning but should go back a little bit with the mouse to before?

3) what should i do when changing graphs in menu to initialize and reset?

Answer (score 0):

In [SciChart](http://www.scichart.com) when you are using the [CategoryDateTimeAxis](http://www.scichart.com/documentation/v4.x/webframe.html#SciChart.Charting~SciChart.Charting.Visuals.Axes.CategoryDateTimeAxis.html), one bar (one data-point) = x Minutes (assuming your data is equal spacing per bar).

For instance, if you have 15-minute (900 seconds) bars on the chart, then 10 bars = 150 minutes (9000 seconds). Therefore all you need to do is to set XAxis.VisibleRange as follows:

```
public void SetRangeToTimeFrame(TimeSpan timeFrame)
{
    // Assuming you have a reference to the data series of type OhlcDataSeries
    int indexMax = dataSeries.XValues.Count - 1;

    // Assuming you know timeframe (one bar = X seconds)
    // If you don;t know this, SciChart tries to calculate it in the 
    // CategoryDateTimeAxis.BarTimeFrame property
    const int timeframe = 900; // for example 900 seconds per bar

    // Calculate the min index to display. Do not go below zero
    int indexMin = Math.Max(indexMax - (timeFrame.TotalSeconds / timeFrame), 0);

    // Set XAxis.VisibleRange equal to the new range
    // OR, Set via binding if you have a property XVisibleRange in ViewModel
    XAxis.VisibleRange = new IndexRange(indexMin, indexMax);
}
```

That really is it!

If you have variable length bars (e.g. one bar is 10 minutes, one is 20 seconds) then your calculation becomes near impossible ... but it is still possible. Let me know if this is the case, I will improve the answer.

(2) and (3) are really different questions and need more clarification before they can be answered.

*Disclaimer: I am the tech lead of the SciChart WPF Project*